# Faster way to extract data from large file

Tags: bash, performance, for-loop, large-data

I have file containing about 40000 frames of Cartesian coordinates of 28 atoms. I need to extract coordinates of atom 21 to 27 from each frame.

I tried using bash script with for-loop.

```
for i in {0..39999}
do
    cat $1 | grep -A 27 "frame $i " | tail -n 6 | awk '{print $2, $3, $4}' >> new_coors.xyz
done
```

Data have following form:

```
28
-1373.82296 frame 0   xyz file generated by terachem
  Re       1.6345663991    0.9571586961    0.3920887712
   N       0.7107677071   -1.0248027788    0.5007181135
   N      -0.3626961076    1.1948218124   -0.4621264246
   C      -1.1299268126    0.0792071086   -0.5595954110
   C      -0.5157993503   -1.1509115191   -0.0469223696
   C       1.3354467762   -2.1017253883    1.0125736017
   C       0.7611763218   -3.3742177216    0.9821756556
   C      -1.1378354025   -2.4089069492   -0.1199253156
   C      -0.4944655989   -3.5108477831    0.4043826684
   C      -0.8597552614    2.3604180994   -0.9043060625
   C      -2.1340008843    2.4846545826   -1.4451933224
   C      -2.4023114639    0.1449111237   -1.0888703147
   C      -2.9292779079    1.3528434658   -1.5302429615
   H       2.3226814021   -1.9233467458    1.4602019023
   H       1.3128699342   -4.2076373780    1.3768411246
   H      -2.1105470176   -2.5059031902   -0.5582958817
   H      -0.9564415355   -4.4988963635    0.3544299401
   H      -0.1913951275    3.2219343258   -0.8231465989
   H      -2.4436044324    3.4620639189   -1.7693069306
   H      -3.0306593902   -0.7362803011   -1.1626515622
   H      -3.9523215784    1.4136948699   -1.9142814745
   C       3.3621999538    0.4972227756    1.1031860016
   O       4.3763020637    0.2022266109    1.5735343064
   C       2.2906331057    2.7428149541    0.0483795630
   O       2.6669163864    3.8206298898   -0.1683800650
   C       1.0351398442    1.4995168190    2.1137684156
   O       0.6510904387    1.8559680025    3.1601927094
  Cl       2.2433490373    0.2064711824   -1.9226174036
```

It works but it takes enormous amount of time, 
In future I will be working with larger file. Is there faster way to do that?

Comment: A file sample would be appreciated...

Comment: Are the frame numbers in file in sorted order?

Comment: Also other commands along with `for` loop are taking memory too, if you could let us know exact requirement then we could do that in a single `awk` itself, as mentioned by Jepessen kindly add samples in your post and let us know then.

Comment: @Adam Srut, please post samples in your post NOT in form of images or as attachment on other sites, kindly do so and let us know then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your program is slow is that you keep on re-reading your input file over and over in your for-loop. You can do everything with reading your file a single time and use awk instead:

```
awk '/frame/{c=0;next}{c++}(c>20 && c<27){ print $2,$3,$4 }' input > output
```

This answer assumes the following form of data:

```
frame ???
??? x y z ???
??? x y z ???
...
frame ???
??? x y z ???
??? x y z ???
...
```

The solution checks if it finds the word `frame` in a line. If so, it sets the atom counter `c` to zero and skips to the next line. From that point forward, it will always read increase the counter if it reads a new line. If the counter is between 20 and 27 (exclusive), it will print the coordinates.

You can now easily expand on this: Assume you want the same atoms but only from frame 1000 till 1500. You can do this by introducing a frame-counter `fc`

```
awk '/frame/{fc++;c=0;next}{c++}(fc>=1000 && fc <=1500) && (c>20 && c<27){ print $2,$3,$4 }' input > output
```

Answer (score 1):

If frames numbers in file are already in sorted order, e.g. they have numbers 0 - 39999 in this order, then maybe something likes this could do the job (not tested, since we don't have a sample input file, as Jepessen suggested):

```
cat $1 | grep -A 27 -E "frame [0-9]+ " | \
awk '{if ($1 == "frame") n = 0; if (n++ > 20) print $2, $3, $4}' > new_coors.xyz
```

(code above made explicitly verbose to be easier to understand and closer to your existing script. If you need a more compact solution check kvantour answer)

Comment: In particular since we talk about efficiency here, drop the unnecessary `cat` in your solution. One less child process  to run.

Comment: I didn't tried to make my solution efficient, but rather make it as similar to OP so its easier to understand by OP. You're right about cat, and grep regex could also be integrated in awk, and in the end the answer could look like kvantour's answer. I opt for clean rather than efficient code, but thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use 2 passes of `grep`, rather than thousands?

Assuming you want the lines 21-27 after every frame, and you don't want to record the frame number itself, the following phrase should get the lines you want, which you can then 'tidy' with awk:

```
grep -A27 ' frame ' | grep -B6 '-----'
```

If you also wanted the frame numbers (I see no evidence), or you really want to restrict the range of frame numbers, you could do that with tee and >( grep 'frame') to generate a second file that you would then need to re-merge. If you added -n to grep then you could easily merge sort the files on line number.

Another way to restrict the frame number without doing multiple passes would be a more complex grep expression that describes the range of numbers (-E because life is too short for backticks):

```
-E ' frame (([0-9]{1,4}|[0-3][0-9]{1,4}) '
```